# Not working while Selenium in Google colaboratory(no new chrome pop up)

Tags: python, selenium, google-colaboratory

I have a trouble in Selenium on Google Colaboratory.

I have tried to auto-login for a portal site in my country.
I learned that when I run the code, then new chrome window should be opened.

But I ran the code below, nothing happened even without error message.

```
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

wd.get("https://nid.naver.com/nidlogin.login")

sleep(0.5)
wd.find_element_by_name('id').send_keys('ID')
sleep(0.5)
wd.find_element_by_name('pw').send_keys('password')
```

Running finished but I didn't have any results...
How can I get a new window?

Comment: where is beginning of you code.

Comment: @furas Those are just code for installing libraries and setting for colab. Anyway I added lines to the post.

Comment: there are also settings for chrome and I see `--headless` which means "not display window" and this is why you don't see chrome.

Comment: Now I released that you run it on `Google Colaboratory` which means external server. You can't see Chrome because code runs on external server and this means Chrome runs on external server and it has access only to monitor assigned to this server but not to your local monitor. Chrome can't run on one computer and display window on another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Google Colaboratory` runs code on server and Chrome runs on server too - so Chrome can display only on monitor connected to this server and you can't see this monitor. And there is no option to redirect image from server's monitor to your monitor - to Google Colaboratory's window on your monitor.

---

If you will run it on your computer then you will not see Chrome because you use the option `"--headless"` which means "not display window". It is often used on servers because the server usually doesn't have a monitor (server is called "headless server" because the monitor looks like a computer's head), and the user couldn't see this monitor.

With option `"--headless"` Chrome doesn't have to render and display page so it may also work faster. This option can be useful even on a local computer.